# c#: Ignore argument exception / An approach or trick to make my code work

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm doing a console app web scraper, basically using Net Core 3.0 and from the part when I want to use proxy or use my own connection I'm having an error with my approach IF statement. Please see below.

Basically if:

```
bool useProxy = false;
proxyFunction(proxy ? null : File.ReadAllLines(//HERE IS PATH TO FILE))
```

So if the bool "useProxy" is false, it returns null which is how I wanted but it still continues on the "File.ReadAllLines" and since the bool "useProxy" is false it pretty much returns an argument exception telling it cannot be null (the File.ReadAllLines) which shouldn't be happening at the very first it shouldn't continue from there anymore as my operator "?" on the "proxyFunction" returns the null already because the bool "useProxy" is false.

Please ignore the "proxyFunction" as it's just a function from a my proxy class on HttpClient to return if bool "useProxy" is null, if not, runs the "File.ReadAllLines" and return its value.

Thank you for the time! :)

Comment: I think you might have the ternary operator backwards? It will return `null` if `proxy` is true, and execute `File.ReadAllLines` if it is false.

Comment: Woops. My bad, I mean, the bool "proxy" is if I want it to work without proxies. Editting now.

Comment: What's the difference between `proxy` and `useProxy` in your code? `File.ReadAllLines` will run only if `proxy` is `false` in your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Did a function with try-catch statement, not a good approach when it comes to being fast/great in performance but solves the problem anyway.

Comment: It is also a concern for maintenance. It will maybe not be obvious for another developper (who could be yourself in one month from now ! ) who has to look at the code and understand what's happening.